# bash test for string being an amount

Tags: shell-script

I am working with a somewhat free form csv file and need to efficiently find expense entries.  My preferable solution would be to test a particular column in every line for an amount.  I tried the following (GNU bash, version 5.0.17) but it's not working (nothing returns "Is a dollar amount"):

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
if [[ $input == [\$]?[0-9][\,]?[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]{2}?$ ]]
then
echo "Is a dollar amount"
else
echo "Is NOT a dollar amount"
fi
```

I have tried the dollar-sign, comma and period just escaped (without the brackets) and that didn't work either.  I single-quoted a parameter containing a dollar-sign (had to).
I changed == to =~ and too many possibilities report "Is a dollar amount".  Searching the web for something like this is almost impossible.  What am I doing wrong?  I thought what I wrote meant was:

- A leading dollar-sign is optional - [$]?
- At least one digit is required - [0-9]
- A comma is optional - [,]?
- Any number of additional digits is acceptable - [0-9]*
- A period is optional - [.]?
- There can be two additional digits but that too is optional - [0-9]{2}?
- Nothing after the last two digits - $

Comment: Can you give examples of a few lines of the CSV file?

Comment: It looks like you're using a regular expression, but in a `[[ ]]` conditional expression, the `==` operator uses glob (wildcard) patterns; you need to use `=~` instead. See the stackoverflow questions ["Are `=` and `=~` equivalent to check simple regular expressions?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919692) and ["bash regular expression different formats"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763227) (and maybe ["How do I test if a variable is a number in Bash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906)).

Comment: Are negative values allowed?

Comment: I would be doing this is python, and using a CSV read library.

Comment: Very much what @ctrl-alt-delor says: the UNIX philosophy, for what it really means in a positive sense, is, "you got tools that are optimized for specific use cases. Use and combine these", not "do everything in your shell". Using Python's built-in `csv` module solves this problem in a [few lines of code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) that are easy to read and much less corner case / error prone.

Answer (score 2):

You likely wanted to use the `=~` operator rather than `==` for the test, and you can't use `?` after `{2}`.

The correct way to say "none or two digits" would be `([0-9]{2})?`.

What you end up with is

```bsh
if [[ $input =~ ^\$?[0-9],?[0-9]*\.?([0-9]{2})?$ ]]; then ...; fi
```

Here I've also anchored the expression to the start of the line with `^` and I've removed some unnecessary square brackets.

If the parts of the string that are optional are not independently optional, you may want to put those parts in parentheses, as in e.g.,

```bsh
if [[ $input =~ ^\$?[0-9](,[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]{2})?$ ]]; then ...; fi
```

This requires at least one digit after the comma, if there is a comma, and two digits after the dot if the is a dot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above post from @they which led me to the answer:

```
if [[ $input =~ ^\$?[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{2})?$ ]]
```

I see I made a number of mistakes. I called the above script "test" and tried several variations (see below) and they all responded as expected.

The following reported "Is a dollar amount"

- ./test 1
- ./test 75
- ./test 453
- ./test '$453'
- ./test 1,234
- ./test 1,234.89
- ./test 1,234,657.89

The following reported "Is NOT a dollar amount"

- ./test 1a234,657.89
- ./test 1,234.657.89  (note two periods)
- ./test 1,234,657.9   (missing cents digit)